# IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-ogm

I am using Spring Data with Hibernate and mongo db. I am encountering the following stack while trying to deploy my webapp into Wildfly 10.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type:
>   class class com.olp.jpa.domain.docu.product.ProductTemplateBean   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:159)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>     ... 35 more

---

The code runs fine when tested in Junit using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. Only during Wildfly deployment, I get this error. Snippets from various artifacts below:

1. web.xml

   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```
2. Spring config

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"

   > 

   ```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.olp"/>

   <tx:annotation-driven />

   <jpa:repositories base-package="com.olp.jpa.domain"  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitMgr"/>
       <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
       <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="ogmVendorAdapter"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="persistenceUnitMgr" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
       <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
           <array>
               <ref bean="persistencePostProcessor"/>
           </array>
       </property>
       <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence_olp.xml"/>
       <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="productHub"/>
       <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.olp.jpa.domain.docu" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="persistencePostProcessor" class="com.olp.jpa.OlpPersistenceUnitPostProcessor"/>

   <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

   <bean id="ogmVendorAdapter" class="com.olp.jpa.OlpHibernateOgmVendorAdapter"/>
   ```
3. JPA conf  (persistence_olp.xml)

   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
     
       org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence
       ENABLE_SELECTIVE

   ```
       <properties>

           <!--
               All other hibernate / mongo properties are externalized and provided by persistence unit post-processor in Spring
           -->

           <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false" />

       </properties>
   ```
4. Entity throwing exception (ProductTemplateBean.java)

   package com.olp.jpa.domain.docu.product;

   @Entity
   @Table(name="phub_product_template")
   public class ProductTemplateBean implements Serializable {

   ```
   @Id
   @DocumentId
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   //@Type(type = "objectid")
   private Long id;

   // Omitting other fields & getters setters for brevity
   ```

   }
5. Wildfly class loader conf ( jboss-deployment-structure.xml )

   ```
       <exclusions>
           <module name="org.hibernate"/>
           <module name="org.hibernate.search.orm"/>
           <module name="org.hibernate.search.engine"/>
           <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
           <module name="org.codehaus"/>
           <module name="resteasy" />
       </exclusions>

   </deployment>
   ```

I would really appreciate if someone can throw some pointers. I have already read through some of the related articles, most of which point to "packagesToScan" property. This is already configured properly.

Breaking my head for a long time ! Thanks in advance for any kind of help here.

Comment: I doubt if `packagesToScan` checks in the subpackages as well. You have `<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.olp.jpa.domain.docu" />` and the `ProductTemplateBean` entity exist in `com.olp.jpa.domain.docu.product` package as well to scan. You may want to add this package and test. Or may be with `com.olp.jpa.domain.docu.**.*`

Comment: Well, it didn't help. I already tried to scan specific packages using 
  <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                <value>com.olp.jpa.domain.docu.product</value>
            </array>
        </property>                   
Still the same error. Not sure, what is so special happening inside Wildfly inspite of disabling their native jpa.

Comment: Infact I had to dump Wildfly deployment for now ( will eventually need it ) and move ahead with Tomcat & Jetty deployment. No issues seen with same code being deployed there. Hence it appears that the Wildfly hibernate library exclusion is not working properly. Probably I'll follow up in Wildfly forum.